# angular 2 variable in property breaks template rendering

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a template that contains this snippet

```
<img src="{{ src }}" onerror="this.src='{{ placeholderSrc }}'" />
```

I couldn't make it work. If I remove the onerror bit:

```
<img src="{{ src }}" />
```

the template works again. If I change placeholderSrc's position:

```
<img src="{{ src }}" onerror="this.src=''" />
{{ placeholderSrc }}
```

It works.

It seems to have something to do with onerror but I'm not sure exactly what.

I'm on RC 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [inbuilt events](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2b20db6c5acd60721e8a5dae2b50cdb1292f8db1/modules/%40angular/platform-webworker/src/web_workers/ui/event_dispatcher.ts#L21):

```html
<img [src]="src" (error)="src = placeholderSrc" />
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPo1GZQCIgV9s9B41U5w?p=preview) for a working example

Comment: while it makes the template work again, the image source isn't replaced upon an error.

Comment: Works like a charm for me - see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPo1GZQCIgV9s9B41U5w?p=preview)